# jquery grep, fitlering with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I will start this question with the statement that I'm really bad with regex.

Said this, I wonder if possible to filter an array using jquery $.grep, match strings with an specific string, something like this:

```
 var a = ["ABC:12", "xx:ABC:2", "ASD:3", "xx:ASD:5"];
 var s = a.split(",");

 var array = $.grep(s, function(x, y) {
   return ??????;
 });
```

so after applying $.grep or any other function which could help, i will need the after ":" number of those with ABC, so my new array would be:

```
array[12, 2];
```

Any help with this??? I would really appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.grep` only select elements of an array which satisfy a filter function.

You need additional step to `$.map` all numbers from grepped array.

```
var a = ["ABC:12", "xx:ABC:2", "ASD:3", "xx:ASD:5"];

var b = $.grep(a, function(item) {
    return item.indexOf("ABC:") >= 0;
});

var array = $.map(b, function(item) {
    return item.split(":").pop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var a = ["ABC:12", "xx:ABC:2", "ASD:3", "xx:ASD:5"];

// map array ,
// test array items for "ABC" string ,
// filter `Number` in strings containing "ABC" ,
// return filtered Numbers , in newly mapped array
var s = $.map(a, function(n) {
  return (/ABC/.test(n) ? Number(n.split(":").filter(Number)) : null)
}); // [12, 2]
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Explain how this code solves the problem.